# Problems connecting to MySQL database from PHP application using shared memory

Tags: php, mysql, shared-memory

I have a very basic PHP page from which I am connecting to a MySQL database.

My MySQL *.ini* file is as follows:

```
skip-show-database
local-infile=0
bind-address=::1
```

I am now reading that connecting via shared memory is faster and more secure so I changed my *.ini* file to this:

```
skip-show-database
local-infile=0
skip-networking
enable-named-pipe
shared-memory
bind-address=::1
```

With these settings, I can access the database from DOS with the mysql.exe command without any issues but if I try to reload my PHP page, I get this error:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I am connecting to the database with:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "serveradmin", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "mysql");
```

I noticed that with *TCP/IP* the database port was **3306** but with shared memory it's **0**.

What am I missing? Could this be it?

Comment: Have you tried explicilty set the port in _.ini_?

Comment: I suggest to stay away from shared memory and to use sockets instead.

Comment: What do I have to change in my.ini to use sockets please?

Answer (score 0):

Try `127.0.0.1` as address to use an TCP/IP connection. If you use `localhost`, socket is tried.

Please note that shared memory connection are not officially supported by mysql and that there are several PHP bugs related to this functionality. Thus if you cannot get it to work, it might mean that it does not work at all.